# text widget integration in android

Tags: android, text

I want to integrate text widget in my application in android studio. I tried running the samples and they are working fine. Now i want to toast the digital text that appears after user input. I want to save that text somehere. I used this code in OnRecognitionEnd() function

```
@Override   
public void onRecognitionEnd() {    
String Result = mEditText.getText().toString();    
Log.d(TAG, "result is: " +Result);  
}
```

Now can you kindly tell me I want to display the text that is being stored in “Result” I used multiple ways but it says UNFORTUNETLY THE APPLICATION HAS STOPPED. For Example i simply did this
TextView textElement = null;
textElement.setText(Result);
Please tell me what I am doing wrong what should i do to display it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do this :

```
TextView textElement = null;
textElement.setText(Result);
```

You will try to setText on null. I suppose the error in your logcat is NullPointerException.

You have to instantiate your textElement.

```
TextView textElement=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.myid);
```

Where "myid" is the id in your layout.xml.